# discord.py - Shard ID None session has been invalidated

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a sharded bot with two scripts:

First looks like this:

```py
bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
...
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel.send(...)
bot.run(token)
```

And second:

```py
bot = commands.AutoShardedBot(
    intents=discord.Intents.all(), shard_ids=[0], shard_count=1, command_prefix=""
)
...
bot.run(token)
```

After I start the bot with these two scripts, after 2 days of real time, the first script gives the following error
[image: error]

And because the on_ready event says to send a message, the message is sent again, and the previous sent message has to be deleted manually.

I searched for this error and don't understand what can raise this error and how to fix it.

I want the session to be always active and does not end with such an error. So that the session does not connect with another Gateway.

Comment: It's not an error, it's just an informational message (hence the word `INFO` next to it). Also - don't do anything in `on_ready`, exactly for this purpose. If you only want something to be done once on startup, use `setup_hook` or a `task`.